# Disable ctrl-alt-del on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

There is a blue screen that appears when you press ctrl-alt-del on windows 7 or vista. I figured out how to disable the taskmanager but users can still shutdown the machine.

How can I prevent them from being able to do this?

Comment: I would suggest to run a fresh antivirus

Comment: Doesn't this have a clear purpose: kiosk applications in which one doesn't want members of the public to restart the system?

Comment: idealmachine: Thats exactly why. I told the client he really doesnt need it but he asked me to look into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable ctrl-alt-del and shutdown for kiosk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234242/disable-ctrl-alt-del-and-shutdown-for-kiosk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is the login system of Windows that traps the CTRL-ALT-DEL combination (and so it is not accessible to user applications), you will need to [change the system's keyboard scancode map](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Miscellaneous/Q_20493187.html) to ignore at least one of those keys.

Comment: Disabling alt solved it. To do that i used the binary 00000000000000000300000000003800000038e000000000

Comment: Heres the text for a .reg file http://www.pastie.org/1314447

Comment: I probably should include the remove script http://www.pastie.org/1314499 just name it anything.reg

Answer (score 1):

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoClose
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (0 = shutdown enabled, 1 = shutdown disabled)


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon]
Value Name: ShutdownWithoutLogon
Data Type: REG_SZ
Value Data: 0
```

Comment: +1 but i dont understand how this works. I still was able to turn off my comp... I looked this up http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938263.aspx and while i didnt notice shutdown grayed out i can do it through that blue screen

Comment: are you looking for a way to disable ctrl+alt+del?

Comment: @HPT: yes. I found out how to disable the taskmanager and now the only way someone can shutdown outside of the designated secret or password way except the blue screen through ctrl+alt+del

Answer (score 0):

You could use AHK ([auto hot key](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) to stop these keys sending what they should, i was considering making a program to do this for the whole keyboard as a joke. You could replace the keys with a message box says "you are not allowed to do that!" or even have a hidden keycombo to put back the functionality of the keys

Comment: AutoHotkey doesnt stop it. I remapped alt, i found how to disbale taskman but this is for a kiosk and the client doesnt want the comp to be shutdown by the public

Comment: Windows does not allow `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`Del` to be remapped this way.