# WinLockDLL.dll and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, dll

Is anyone familiar with **WinLockDLL.dll**?

In an old program someone wrote up at work, we use functions within WinLockDLL.dll in order to do such things as disable ctrl-alt-del, hide the desktop, etc. This worked fine for Windows XP.

However, now that everyone's upgraded to Windows 7, the DLL's functions don't seem to have any effect. (As a matter of fact, Windows 7 doesn't even *have* that DLL; I had to copy it from an older computer...)

I asked this question at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137164/winlockdll-dll-functions-in-windows7) (in which the programming aspect was covered), and people there referred me here, where someone might know more about this DLL, and whether it has an equivalent in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard of this before, and a quick search on MSDN turns up that it's a [CodeProject program](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/AntonioWinLock.aspx), not a built-in supported tool.

If you're trying to do control elements of the desktop such as the taskbar, Ctrl+Alt+Del menu options, etc. then you should look at using Group Policy. There is a comprehensive listing of [all Group Policy settings](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=25250) available on Microsoft Technet.

If you are in a corporate setting and are managing settings on many machines, you should do this with Group Policy in Active Directory. If that is the case, you should have this question migrated to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). If this is on a smaller, non-centrally-manged system, check out [How to apply group policy settings to specific local accounts in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/134066/20088).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links for the disabling, for the rest of it I would  end the explorer shell itself via batch, then run the One testing program,  then restart it after the testing program is stopped? That should clear out some of the rest of the things, Other things you can use "NET Stop" for killing themes or other unnessisary items like even the network/internet.  When that isnt enough devcon can completly disable the devices themselves.

most of the time when discussed it is all about "group policy" and adjusting it there, you can batch in group policy changes to the registry quick enough.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234242/disable-ctrl-alt-del-and-shutdown-for-kiosk

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic15702.html (mainly the idea of using autohotkey to shift keys about, as this doesnt work in 7) there are other keyboard "hook" programs but what is said here probably applies "Windows does not allow Ctrl-Alt-Del to be remapped this way." – grawity

[Disable ctrl-alt-del on windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/213327/disable-ctrl-alt-del-on-windows-7-via-reg)

[How can I disable the CTRL-ALT-DEL key combination completely on XP/Vista/7?](https://superuser.com/questions/142176/how-can-i-disable-the-ctrl-alt-del-key-combination-completely-on-xp-vista-7)

Your question really was more of a programming question, actually applying a loose DLL or writing/compiling VB scriping.